# Attempting to generate types from other types in Scala

Tags: scala, types, slick

I'm using Slick on a project and for that I require a Slick representation of my rows and then also an in memory representation. I'm going to use a much simpler example here for brevity. Say for example I have both these types:

```
type RawType =
    (String, Int, Boolean)

type RawTypeRep =
    (Rep[String], Rep[Int], Rep[Boolean])
```

Is there a way to generate one from the other so I don't have to update them in lockstep?

Or perhaps generate them both from a case class? I do have a case class representation, but it's actually slightly different from the types I have because when I hydrate the case class I do some mutations which results in type changes.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly know the steps, but two things pop to my mind :
1. is exploring scala macros, which should be able to do that, even though I wouldn't know how
2. is the fact the slick comes with a codegenerator for generating classes based on your database, maybe that's something you may be willing to use ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job for [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), though I'm not sure exactly the best way to apply it to your case. The best I can think of is not to generate one from the other, but to at least verify at compile time that the two match up:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.poly._
import shapeless.ops.tuple._

object ToRep extends (Id ~> Rep) {
  def apply[A](a: A): Rep[A] = ???
}
type CheckRep[A, B] = Mapper.Aux[A, ToRep.type, B]

type RawType = (String, Int, Boolean)
type RawTypeRep = (Rep[String], Rep[Int], Rep[Boolean])
type RawTypeRepWrong = (Rep[String], Rep[String], Rep[Boolean])

implicitly[CheckRep[RawType, RawTypeRep]] // compiles
implicitly[CheckRep[RawType, RawTypeRepWrong]] // compile error
```

I am guessing there's probably a better way to handle this given a step back to a larger context. Might be worthwhile to skim the documentation for shapeless to see the kinds of things it can do and see if that gives you any idea.

Comment: Fortunately the compiler will already warn me if they are incorrect. I'm just trying to go from `n` updates to 1 update.